# Hashed list into buckets

Tags: python, list, hashset

After hashing list of names using ASCII I got a sum list `asciis = [382, 409, 385, 302, 371, 387, 371]` so using modulo `%` received list like this `w = [6, 1, 1, 6, 3, 3, 3]`.

So now I am supposed to put first list into list of buckets I have 7 now. so it should to look like `buckets = [[], [409, 385], [], [371, 387], [], [], [382, 302], []]`.

How should I put them accordingly?
So far I got:

```
def add(self, word):
    hashed_word = self.get_hash(word)
    asciis = [sum([(ch) for ch in word]) for word in hashed_word]
    w = [s % len(self.buckets) for s in asciis]
    for i in enumerate(asciis):
        if i not in self.buckets[i for i in enumerate(w)]:
            self.buckets.append[w]
            if len(self.buckets) == self.size:
                self.rehash()
```

Comment: If you have 7 "buckets" in a list, you could use the hash code as the index in the list: `buckets = [[], [409, 385], [], [371, 387, 371], [], [], [382, 302]]` But the numbers would be replaced with the actual strings.

Comment: okey thank you so much